# Program doesnt work if i changed Visual studio version 2008 to 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

Hi i keep getting this error in my program, it just to work in visual studio 2008 but im using 2010 and isnt working and keep getting this errors messenges

```
Error   4   error LNK2019: símbolo externo "public: bool __thiscall C_DSPlib::GeneraCoeficientesCosenoAlzado(float *,short,float,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?GeneraCoeficientesCosenoAlzado@C_DSPlib@@QAE_NPAMFMII@Z) sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función __catch$?InicializacionesComunes@C_Serial@@QAEXXZ$0    C:\SilverHeart\Serial.obj   SilverHeart
Error   5   error LNK2019: símbolo externo "public: short __thiscall C_DSPlib::PuntoMedio(long *,int)" (?PuntoMedio@C_DSPlib@@QAEFPAJH@Z) sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "public: bool __thiscall C_Serial::DibujaPunto(unsigned int,bool)" (?DibujaPunto@C_Serial@@QAE_NI_N@Z)   C:\SilverHeart\Serial.obj   SilverHeart
Error   6   error LNK2019: símbolo externo "public: bool __thiscall C_DSPlib::ECG_DefineFiltros(float *,float *,float *,float *,float *,float *,float *,float *)" (?ECG_DefineFiltros@C_DSPlib@@QAE_NPAM0000000@Z) sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "public: bool __thiscall C_Serial::SetCoeficientesFiltros(float *,float *,float *,float *,float *,float *,float *,float *)" (?SetCoeficientesFiltros@C_Serial@@QAE_NPAM0000000@Z)   C:\SilverHeart\Serial.obj   SilverHeart
Error   9   error LNK2019: símbolo externo _HtmlHelpA@16 sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "long __stdcall WndProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WndProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)  C:\SilverHeart\SilverHeart.obj  SilverHeart
Error   10  error LNK2019: símbolo externo "void __cdecl dl_deleteAll(struct s_DLlist *,int)" (?dl_deleteAll@@YAXPAUs_DLlist@@H@Z) sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "long __stdcall DlgAbrirECG(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?DlgAbrirECG@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)    C:\SilverHeart\SilverHeart.obj  SilverHeart
```

Comment: Try to do a `Rebuild All`

Answer (score 1):

This can be the case if you link against other libraries that were built using a previous version of Visual Studio.

You have to rebuild all referenced libraries with the same new toolchain so that linking can be done smoothly.

If it doesn't solve your problem, then give some code (the code from the referenced functions for example) because without more information, there are 5000 possible causes that can lead to linking errors.